# Excel VBA: Problems copying rows to next blank row of another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where I add a person's details in columns A-K [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS2HL.jpg)

I am trying to use VBA to run code everytime row L has "Yes" in it, and then look for any "Yes"'s in columns M-T and copy the entire row from the current sheet "New Refs" to the corresponding tab (eg. if "Yes" in column M, copy the row to the "ASD 5P" tab).

I have the following code, but it keeps overwriting rows that are already there. I need it to look for the next blank row in the corresponding tab, and paste it to that, without overwriting or deleting the other rows that are already there. Here is the code I am using currently...

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim KeyCells As Range

  ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
  ' cause an alert when they are changed.
  Set KeyCells = Range("K:S")

  If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim lastrow As Long
  lastrow = Sheets("New Refs").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  Dim x As Long
  x = 4
  Dim rng As Range
  For Each rng In Sheets("New Refs").Range("M4:M" & lastrow)
      If rng.Value2 = "Yes" And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "K")) <> vbNullString And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "L")) = "Yes" Then
          rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ASD 5P").Cells(x, 1)
          x = x + 1
      End If
  Next rng
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True


  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  lastrow = Sheets("New Refs").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  x = 4
  For Each rng In Sheets("New Refs").Range("N4:N" & lastrow)
      If rng.Value2 = "Yes" And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "K")) <> vbNullString And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "L")) = "Yes" Then
          rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ASD PD").Cells(x, 1)
          x = x + 1
      End If
  Next rng
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  lastrow = Sheets("New Refs").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  x = 4
  For Each rng In Sheets("New Refs").Range("O4:O" & lastrow)
      If rng.Value2 = "Yes" And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "K")) <> vbNullString And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "L")) = "Yes" Then
          rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("IY Group").Cells(x, 1)
          x = x + 1
      End If
  Next rng
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  lastrow = Sheets("New Refs").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  x = 4
  For Each rng In Sheets("New Refs").Range("P4:P" & lastrow)
      If rng.Value2 = "Yes" And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "K")) <> vbNullString And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "L")) = "Yes" Then
          rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Dina").Cells(x, 1)
          x = x + 1
      End If
  Next rng
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  lastrow = Sheets("New Refs").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  x = 4
  For Each rng In Sheets("New Refs").Range("Q4:Q" & lastrow)
      If rng.Value2 = "Yes" And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "K")) <> vbNullString And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "L")) = "Yes" Then
          rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Indiv. Par.").Cells(x, 1)
          x = x + 1
      End If
 Next rng
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True   

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  lastrow = Sheets("New Refs").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  x = 4
  For Each rng In Sheets("New Refs").Range("R4:R" & lastrow)
      If rng.Value2 = "Yes" And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "K")) <> vbNullString And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "L")) = "Yes" Then
          rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ASD Psy. Ed.").Cells(x, 1)
          x = x + 1
      End If
  Next rng
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  lastrow = Sheets("New Refs").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  x = 4
  For Each rng In Sheets("New Refs").Range("S4:S" & lastrow)
      If rng.Value2 = "Yes" And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "K")) <> vbNullString And Trim(Cells(rng.Row, "L")) = "Yes" Then
          rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ADHD Psy. Ed.").Cells(x, 1)
          x = x + 1
      End If
  Next rng
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True   
  End If
End Sub
```

Please advise?

***UPDATE*** My header rows look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mqo3.jpg)

Comment: To clarify, so when a cell in column **L** has been changed to a value of `Yes`, you want to copy the data from that row to all sheets set as `Yes` in that row? Also, do your sheet names correspond to the headings in column `M` onwards?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I also find that my current code also seems to add duplicates to the destination sheets sometimes.

Comment: Are there duplicates in the source?

Comment: No, not duplicates. But if I amend anything in the destination sheet (such as the spelling of a name), when the code runs again it overwrites my changes. I'm guessing it's all part of my bigger "overwriting" problem rather than a separate issue. I suppose what I'm saying is I only want the code to work on the row I am editing, rather than checking through the whole "New refs" list, as it is doing at the moment. Once my row been copied to another sheet(s), I don't want the code to affect any changes I make to the copy in the destination sheet.

Comment: You have a massive amount of repeat code which for you could refactor into a select statement for example using  Select Case Target.Column  .......Case 13 Then ........

Comment: You could pull out finding the last row into a function that accepts worksheet as argument and re-use that as well. At the moment if x is being reset that is why you are overwriting. So for example you could have rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ASD 5P").Cells(GetLastRow(Sheets("ASD 5P") + 1), 1)

Comment: Please don't rely on the following as it may contain mistakes but may give you some idea.... https://pastebin.com/qAy55VQQ

Comment: QHarr - This looks promising, however, when I try it I get an error message stating "Compile error: Variable not defined", which points to testCondit under Case 13. Any guidance as to what I need to do to correct this please?

Comment: Oops testCondit should be testCondition throughout. I haven't run this and so maybe buggy. It was more an overview. You might need to check  testCondition does evaluate properly and in the position it is assigned, otherwise move it back down into each case statement after the For Each..

Comment: Ok, changed it to testCondition throughout. It kept causing an error where it was, so took your advice and moved it down into each "Case", pasting it into a new line after For Each rng... However, the code didn't seem to do anything after that.  Hate to be a pest, but could you please re-post the code with the corrections you have identified for me? In case I've done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Had to get some things finished at work but.. there are different ways you can approach this, below is one:

Following are the assumption I made:

- Trigger column will be `Column L` in your sheet
- You only want to copy from `Column A` to `Column K`
- To check if row already exists in the sheets where row is copied, I am using RIO (`Column C`) as a unique identifier

In your `Worksheet_Change` sub make the call to `CopyCurrentRowToSheets` sub as per screenshot below (NOTE: I used `Sheet8` when developing this code):
[image]

> Add reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` by: In your VBA editor, select the **Tools** menu. Then select **References...** option. This will open **References** window (screen print below). Scroll down and select **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** from the list and press **OK** button
>   [image]

Then in a module, add the following sub:

```
Sub CopyCurrentRowToSheets(ByVal oTarget As Range)
    Dim oW As Worksheet: Set oW = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8")     ' Change the sheet name
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim dSTU As New Scripting.Dictionary     ' Requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim iLR As Long

    ' Capture sheets to update
    For Each oRange In oW.Range("M" & oTarget.Row & ":" & Chr(oW.Cells(1, oW.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 64) & oTarget.Row)
        dSTU.Add Cells(1, oRange.Column).Value, oRange.Value
    Next

    ' Check if we need to update the sheets by checking the value in column L
    If Trim(LCase(oTarget.Value)) = "yes" Then

        ' Loop to go through all sheets in current workbook
        For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            ' Check if current sheet is one of the sheet that need updating
            If dSTU.Exists(oWS.Name) Then

                ' Check if current sheet should be updated
                If Trim(LCase(dSTU(oWS.Name))) = "yes" Then

                    ' Check if current row already exists in the target sheet
                    If Application.IfNa(Application.Match(oW.Cells(oTarget.Row, 3).Value, oWS.Columns(3), 0), "") = "" Then
                        iLR = oWS.Range("A" & oWS.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        oW.Range("A" & oTarget.Row & ":K" & oTarget.Row).Copy oWS.Range("A" & iLR & ":K" & iLR)
                    End If

                End If
            End If

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried what you said, but get the following error "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" which is linked to "Dim dSTU As New Scripting.Dictionary". I'm guessing this has something to do with your comment that this line 'Requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime'. Please advise what I need to do here?

Comment: Have you added the reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`? (as the comment in my code suggests?

Comment: No, that's what I'm asking. I don't know what Microsoft Scripting Runtime is?

Comment: Also make sure that the sheet names in your columns (starting from `Column M`) are exactly the same as what your sheets are called

Comment: Thank you, done that. Now have error message "Run-time error 457: This key is already associated with an element of this collection". The debugger points me to the line...dSTU.Add Cells(1, oRange.Column).Value, oRange.Value

Comment: That would only happen if you have 2 or more columns with same sheet name. Can you check the sheet names in your column and make sure there aren't any duplicate sheet names?

Comment: Can you also check the value of `Cells(1, oRange.Column).Value` when it throws that error? you can do this by either highlighting it and right click and select `Add Watch...`. Then in your watch window it will give you the value.. or you can highlight it and just hover your mouse over it

Comment: Gives me value 51251329, which is one of the "RIO" numbers from row C?

Comment: Looks like its running update when column `C` is being updated. Did you add the first step in my answer? Add the call to `CopyCurrentRowToSheets` sub in your `Worksheet_Change` for `New Refs` sheet with `IF` condition as I outlined in my answer

Comment: I did the steps you gave me.

Comment: Any chance I could share a copy of my sheet with you to take a look at?

Comment: I could email it?

Comment: Send me your email and ill email you back. My indemnity insurance doesn't allow me to work on non-contracted work but can give it a quick go